# 文字列の中から区切り文字で仕切って特定の要素を取り出したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

C#で以下のような文字列があるとします。

```
test1#2.00,2.00,4.07,sample1:sample2|test2#3.04,-2.59,4.07,tttt1:t2t2|testest#3.04,-2.59,4.07,tatata:chichichi
```

シャープの後のカンマで区切られた4つめの要素のみを抜き出して結合し、以下のような1つの文字列にしたいです。

```
sample1:sample2,tttt1:t2t2,tatata:chichichi,
```

以下のようなプログラムを書いて同じ出力を得られたのですが、

```
var combineStr = "";
var strArray = "test1#2.00,2.00,4.07,sample1:sample2|test2#3.04,-2.59,4.07,tttt1:t2t2|testest#3.04,-2.59,4.07,tatata:chichichi";
foreach (string message in strArray.ToString().Split(new Char[] { '|' }))
{
    var strArray1 = message.Split(new Char[] { '#' });
    var commaList = strArray1[1].Split(new Char[] { ',' });
    combineStr += commaList[3];
    combineStr += ",";
}
System.Console.WriteLine(combineStr);
```

もうちょっと簡単に短く書く方法はないでしょうか？

実際には

```
sample1:sample2,tttt1:t2t2,tatata:chichichi
```

のように最後のカンマをなくした状態で出力できるとより嬉しいです。

.NET Framework 3.5の環境を使っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これぐらいでしょうか？

```
var str = "test1#2.00,2.00,4.07,sample1:sample2|test2#3.04,-2.59,4.07,tttt1:t2t2|testest#3.04,-2.59,4.07,tatata:chichichi";
var combined = String.Join(",",
    str.Split('|').Select(s => s.Split('#')[1].Split(',')[3])
);
Console.WriteLine(combined);
```

- [`String.Split`メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)はオーバーロードがあり、[特にオプションを指定しない場合](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___)、`params`指定されているため、文字配列を作らなくても引数として渡せます。
- [`Enumerable.Select`拡張メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)を使用すれば、値を変換することができます。
- [`String.Concatメソッド`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.8)で単純な結合、[`String.Join`メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8)で文字列を挟みながらの結合がそれぞれできます。

---

`String.Concatメソッド`や`String.Join`メソッドのうち`IEnumerable<T>`を受け付けるオーバーロードが追加されたのは.NET Framework 4.0からです。そのため、それ以前の環境では[`Enumerable.ToArray()`拡張メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8)でいったん配列に変換する必要があります。

```
// .NET Framework 3.5向け
var combined = String.Join(",",
    str.Split('|').Select(s => s.Split('#')[1].Split(',')[3]).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！ただ、.NET Framework 3.5を使用すると`エラー CS1503 引数 2: は 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' から 'string[]' へ変換することはできません。`と出てしまうのですが、これはどうしたら直りますか？

Comment: @taichi .NET Framework 3.5は12年以上前のもので、Windows 8以降は標準搭載されなくなっています。このように特別古いバージョンを扱うのであれば、質問文に明記してください。

Comment: @taichi 回答を更新しましたが、エラーは解消しましたでしょうか？

Comment: 無事動作いたしました！本当にありがとうございます